# Delete bullet points in footer menu

Tags: footer

How can I remove the bullet points in my footer menu. (background: created a footer menu with links to my pages, then used "custom menu widget" and moved the widget in my footer.)

See screenshots. 
Now I see that on the frontend it shows up with bullets. I don't want the bullet point. Plus would like to change the typeface too.

Any advice?
Thanks
[image]
[image]

Comment: This will depend on what theme you're using - you'll need some CSS to override the website's standard styling for that element. What's the website's URL?

Answer (score 1):

Tak clss of that widget and add css for remove bullet

```
    ul {
     list-style: none;
   }
```